# Matlab feature selection

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, runtime-error, feature-selection

I am trying to learn relevant features in a `300*299` training matrix by taking a random row from it as my test data and applying `sequentialfs` on it. I have used the following code:

```
>> Md1=fitcdiscr(xtrain,ytrain);
>> func = @(xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest) sum(ytest ~= predict(Md1,xtest));
>> learnt = sequentialfs(func,xtrain,ytrain)
```

`xtrain` and `ytrain` are `299*299` and `299*1` respectively. Predict will give me the predicted label for `xtest`(which is some random row from original xtrain).

However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
Error using crossval>evalFun (line 480)
The function '@(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest)sum(ytest~=predict(Md1,xtest))' generated the following error:
X must have 299 columns.

Error in crossval>getFuncVal (line 497)
funResult = evalFun(funorStr,arg(:));

Error in crossval (line 343)
    funResult = getFuncVal(1, nData, cvp, data, funorStr, []);

Error in sequentialfs>callfun (line 485)
    funResult = crossval(fun,x,other_data{:},...

Error in sequentialfs (line 353)
                crit(k) = callfun(fun,x,other_data,cv,mcreps,ParOptions);

Error in new (line 13)
    learnt = sequentialfs(func,xtrain,ytrain)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: does `xtest` have 299 columns?

Comment: Yes it does. It is a 1*299 row vector.

Comment: I suggest you add a [mcve], else we can not test it

Answer (score 1):

You should build your classifier *inside* `func`, not before. 
`sequentialfs` calls the function each time on different sets, and a classifier must be built specifically for each set, using only the features `sequentialfs` selected for that iteration.

I'm not sure I managed to be clear, in practice you should move the first line of your code inside the body of `func`

Source: [MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/sequentialfs.html)